# Динамические данные в iOS

Tags: swift, ios

Здравствуйте.
Простой для вас но сложный для меня.
Есть приложение -> онлайн магазин

Где правильно хранить добавленные товары в корзину, формата - [IDтовара : количество] ?

Имею в распоряжении:

1. `NSUserDefaults`
2. `core data`
3. чтение.запись в обычный `plist`
4. `SQLite`

Сам думаю использовать 3 вариант

Подскажите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefaults` - bplist.
Если нужен полный контроль над plist/bplist, используй `NSPropertyListSerialization`.
SQLite - это готовая эффективная структура данных для поиска, вставки, удаления.

Зависит от того, какие цели преследуются при сохранении покупки.

Comment: Вы знаете, немного прочитал про coreddata sqlite, сделал вывод(возможно ошибочный), что эти "гиганты" не очень подходят для моей тривиальной задачи хранения 50b данных.

С вашей помощью узнал про NSPropertyListSerialization - круто

Answer (score 1):

CoreData - просто, эффективно и хорошо документировано.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы просто добавил к "ЮзерМенеджер"у массив "корзина" и туда добавлял данные с типом  "Товар".

Comment: Если это тот ЮзерМенеджер про который я подумал, то думаю прицепляя туда словарь "Товар", я навлеку гнев модераторов аррле сторе